# Question Mark as Query Parameter?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, sqldatasource, querystringparameter

I have stumbled upon a DataSource sample at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.querystringparameter(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.querystringparameter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

The code is as follows

```
<%@Page  Language="C#" %>
<%@Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@Import Namespace="System.Data.Common" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
private void UpdateRecords(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
  // This method is an example of batch updating using a
  // data source control. The method iterates through the rows
  // of the GridView, extracts each CheckBox from the row and, if
  // the CheckBox is checked, updates data by calling the Update
  // method of the data source control, adding required parameters
  // to the UpdateParameters collection.
  CheckBox cb;
  foreach(GridViewRow row in this.GridView1.Rows) {
    cb = (CheckBox) row.Cells[0].Controls[1];
    if(cb.Checked) {
      string oid = (string) row.Cells[1].Text;
      MyAccessDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add(new Parameter("date",TypeCode.DateTime,DateTime.Now.ToString()));
      MyAccessDataSource.UpdateParameters.Add(new Parameter("orderid",TypeCode.String,oid));
      MyAccessDataSource.Update();
      MyAccessDataSource.UpdateParameters.Clear();
    }
  }
}
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <head runat="server">
    <title>ASP.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

<!-- Security Note: The SqlDataSource uses a QueryStringParameter,
     Security Note: which does not perform validation of input from the client.
     Security Note: To validate the value of the QueryStringParameter, handle the Selecting event. -->

      <asp:SqlDataSource
        id="MyAccessDataSource"
        runat="server"
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyPasswordProtectedAccess.providerName%>"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyPasswordProtectedAccess%>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, RequiredDate, ShippedDate FROM Orders WHERE EmployeeID=?"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE Orders SET ShippedDate=? WHERE OrderID = ?">
        <SelectParameters>
          <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="empId" QueryStringField="empId" />
        </SelectParameters>
      </asp:SqlDataSource>

      <asp:GridView
        id ="GridView1"
        runat="server"
        DataSourceID="MyAccessDataSource"
        AllowPaging="True"
        PageSize="10"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
          <columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
              <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" />
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Order" DataField="OrderID" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Order Date" DataField="OrderDate" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Required Date" DataField="RequiredDate" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Shipped Date" DataField="ShippedDate" />
          </columns>
      </asp:GridView>

      <asp:Button
        id="Button1"
        runat="server"
        Text="Update the Selected Records As Shipped"
        OnClick="UpdateRecords" />

      <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" />

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried this code. But the server returns

**Incorrect syntax near '?'. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
 Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '?'.**

What do `EmployeeID=?`, `ShippedDate=?` and `OrderID = ?` specify in `SelectCommand` and `UpdateCommand`?
Are they properly written?

How to make this code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three parameters should be replaced with

```
EmployeeID = @empId
ShippedDate = @date
OrderID = @ordered
```

MSDN's samples sometimes don't work.

Answer (score 2):

Some database systems use anonymous parameters, usually signalled by a `?`. You then have to provide the parameters in the correct sequence.

Other systems use named parameters. SqlServer uses a `@name` syntax. You could then provide the parameters out of order, because they are matched on name instead of position.

Change that `WHERE EmployeeID=?` into `WHERE EmployeeID=@empId` to match the name of your parameter.

Comment: does that mean the sample was badly written?

Comment: I have changed EmployeeId=@empId, which is fine. What do I do with 'ShippedDate=?' and 'OrderID = ?'

Comment: @user1978421 you should name the parameters in a similar way. Note that you don't have parameter definitions for them yet. The sample targets an Access database, which does use `?` for params.