# In ASP.NET, why is there always a prompt saying, ‘There was a grammar error around the ‘？’ about my SQL? I use the SQL Server connection at this time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I use a listview control at first:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
     ItemPlaceholderID="itemholder">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href='newsdetail.aspx?nid=<%#Eval("news_id") %>'>                       
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Here is it's `SqlDataSource` control, but when I run this page, it always tells me that

> There was a grammar error around the '?'

about my SQL:

[image]

Comment: Try `@ncid` instead of the `?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SqlDataSource` control requires named parameter(s) instead anonymous parameter(s) with question marks, try changing your query to use named parameter which same as query string parameter name (i.e. `@news_ncid`):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:wangkunConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="select t_imgs.*, t_news.* from (t_imgs inner join t_news on t_imgs.img_id = t_news.news_imgtitle) where news_ncid=@news_ncid">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="news_ncid" QueryStringField="ncid" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="1" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Reference:

[Question Mark as Query Parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977431/question-mark-as-query-parameter)